# Linux Module Programming fails and caught in loop

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

OK, So I am programming this for a HW assignment but could either use some help or insight. I know I've read everywhere that you shouldnt open files in modules but its our assignment...

Anyway my module code is here:
http://pastebin.com/LU8hWraL

and my user level code is here:
http://pastebin.com/RC0Zk1kQ

Ok, my issue is that sometimes it works, other times it doesnt... most of the time when it doesnt work, it catches in a loop on the kernel and I dont understand what is causing the issue and how I can resolve it. Any help on this situation would be incredibly appreciated, I just am getting frustrated having to constantly shut down and restart my VM.

Even if someone tells me how to find the error when my VM loops like that...?

Comment: You may want to try using a debugger on your kernel.

Comment: can't find many good sources on debugging in the kernel... any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to use [`kernel_read()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.7/source/fs/exec.c#L787) and don't do these things yourself.

There might be two issues here

- you give `&filpRead->f_pos` as parameter to `read` and `write`, which is for kernel internal use.
- when you encrypt or decrypt the data, you might not get the same amount of bytes you read. So writing the same amount of data as you read could be a problem too.

Take both with a grain of salt, since it's quite some time ago, since I've looked at kernel programming.